# How to play HTML5 or Flash games offilne in Ubuntu?

Tags: flash, games, downloads, html

I have noticed that there are some very rich HTLM5 games now, simply looking in the Chrome store you can see many. And there are a handful of great flash games.

Is it possible to download HTML5 or flash games and play them offline in Ubuntu?

For example, I setup an Angry Birds launcher in Unity,but I can only play it online. Would be great to know, thank you!

Comment: probably not since you play against a website, you don't download a game. And still you need a browser to play a html/flash game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some (but not all) Flash games store their game data in your temporary internet files folder. The catch is the file is not going to be named anything normal, so you have to search through all the .swf files in your temporary folder to find it. As far as I know you can't do the same thing with HTML5 however.